Return the list of all registered models in MLflow
I'm using mlflow on databricks and I've trained some models, that I can see in the "registered models" page.
Is there a way to extract the list of these models in code?
Something like
import mlflow
mlflow.set_tracking_uri("databricks")
model_infos = mlflow.tracking.MlflowClient().some_method_to_list_registered_models() 

for model_info in model_infos:
    print(f"Name: {model_info.name}, Version: {model_info.latest_versions[0].version}")


To get all registered models
mlflow.search_registered_models()

You will have to write a proper function to convert it into the required format here is an example for you:
def get_Models():
    client = mlflow.MlflowClient()
    data = client.search_registered_models()
    models = []
    for model in data:
        models.append(model.name)
    result = []
    for model in models:
        model_versions = {"name": model}
        data = client.search_model_versions(filter_string =f"name='{model}'", order_by=["version_number DESC"])
        versions = list(map(lambda x: dict(x), data))
        model_versions["latest_versions"] = versions
        result.append(model_versions)
    return result


Thanks, this solved my question. Only difference, I had to order by "version" instead of "version_number"
